Why is 'static lifetime needed in this scenario?
I am currently learning Rust by making a dummy ECS, given the following function:
pub fn add_component<T: Component + 'static>(&mut self, component: T) {
        let type_id = TypeId::of::<T>(); 
}

I won't compile without 'static -
I don't understand why, since I am taking ownership of component - why is Rust worried about this component getting de-allocated.
the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
the parameter type `T` must be valid for the static lifetime

As long as it exists within the function scope (which it does) it should be good.
EDIT:
Component is defined as:
trait Component {
    fn update(&self);

    fn render(&self);
}


That explains the error. Thanks! Now I'm curious why TypeId::of needs a static lifetime. It doesn't event take an instance of the type, of course the type is 'static? It's not going to un-define itself. I have a lot to learn! Thanks

The error is simply because TypeId::of requires it's type parameter to be 'static:

pub fn of<T>() -> TypeId
where
    T: 'static + ?Sized,



A TypeId is currently only available for types which ascribe to 'static, but this limitation may be removed in the future.

So TypeId::of doesn't inherently need 'static, but the current implementation does. Also note that Foo<'a> and Foo<'b> are different types and would have to produce different TypeIds.
